# mongodb aggregate query in node?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am trying to use a very basic aggregate query in mongoDB and then apply that to node.

I am working on this dataset in mongoDB:

```
> db.grades.find().pretty()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5276c13ddc170c04635c1eaf"),
        "student" : "Joe",
        "assignment" : "hw2",
        "grade" : 80
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5276c13ddc170c04635c1eb0"),
        "student" : "Joe",
        "assignment" : "hw3",
        "grade" : 85
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5276c13ddc170c04635c1eb1"),
        "student" : "Joe",
        "assignment" : "exam",
        "grade" : 100
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5276c13ddc170c04635c1eb3"),
        "student" : "Steve",
        "assignment" : "hw2",
        "grade" : 90
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5276c13ddc170c04635c1eb4"),
        "student" : "Steve",
        "assignment" : "hw3",
        "grade" : 100
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5276c13ddc170c04635c1eb5"),
        "student" : "Steve",
        "assignment" : "exam",
        "grade" : 100
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5276c13ddc170c04635c1eb7"),
        "student" : "Amanda",
        "assignment" : "hw2",
        "grade" : 90
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5276c13ddc170c04635c1eb8"),
        "student" : "Amanda",
        "assignment" : "hw3",
        "grade" : 80
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5276c13ddc170c04635c1eb9"),
        "student" : "Amanda",
        "assignment" : "exam",
        "grade" : 100
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5276c13ddc170c04635c1eba"),
        "student" : "Susan",
        "assignment" : "hw1",
        "grade" : 100
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5276c13ddc170c04635c1ebb"),
        "student" : "Susan",
        "assignment" : "hw2",
        "grade" : 90
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5276c13ddc170c04635c1ebc"),
        "student" : "Susan",
        "assignment" : "hw3",
        "grade" : 85
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5276c13ddc170c04635c1ebd"),
        "student" : "Susan",
        "assignment" : "exam",
        "grade" : 80
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5276c13cdc170c04635c1eae"),
        "student" : "Joe",
        "assignment" : "hw1",
        "grade" : 90,
        "date_returned" : ISODate("2013-11-03T23:44:18.774Z")
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5276c13ddc170c04635c1eb2"),
        "student" : "Steve",
        "assignment" : "hw1",
        "grade" : 80,
        "date_returned" : ISODate("2013-11-03T23:44:31.496Z")
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5276c13ddc170c04635c1eb6"),
        "student" : "Amanda",
        "assignment" : "hw1",
        "grade" : 100,
        "date_returned" : ISODate("2013-11-04T00:59:49.446Z")
}
>


> db.grades.find().pretty().count()
16
>
```

Now, this is the aggregate query I want to run in node:

```
> db.grades.aggregate([{$group: {_id: "$student"}}])
{
        "result" : [
                {
                        "_id" : "Susan"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : "Amanda"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : "Steve"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : "Joe"
                }
        ],
        "ok" : 1
}
```

This is my attempt in node I am using. I am using express to set up routes.

```
app.get('/Work5_6', function(req, res){

    // connect to collection
    db.collection('grades').aggregate( {$group: {_id: "$student"}} , function (err, result) {   

        //if there's an error 
         if(err) throw err;

        //if there is no more results
        if (!result) {
        console.dir("xNo Document found!");

            res.send('This is a test page...',200);

        }

        //...do stuff here to your doc
        console.dir("value of result is:");
        console.dir(result);

    }); 

});
```

And this is the result i get in the console:

```
'value of result is:'
[]
```

How do i get access to the values of "result" that are returned from my aggregate query in node? Appreciate some help.

Comment: why are you using aggregate?  You just want a list of distinct student  values, just use db.grades.distinct("student")

Comment: Agreed.  But if you're just trying to play around with `aggregate`, then your code should work; it did when I tried it.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky- this jsut a basic aggregate query I am trying because I was trying a more complex one and thought I would just ask a basic question to get the basics right and then hopefully apply that to the more complex query.

Comment: @JohnnyHK - when you say it worked you mean you are not getting the empty array "[]"? I will look at mine again...

Comment: @HattrickNZ Yes, the result contained the unique student names.

Comment: @JohnnyHK tks but why is it nor working for me? how come I get an empty array? I am not even getting to the res.send line. I'll keep looking...